# Why TCP TIME-WAIT State is present at both ends after a connection termination?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, tcp, protocols

I am reading how the TCP states work and especially the connection termination part.

All of the books or online material I read, shows that for the termination procedure these states are followed from the side initiated (active) the connection termination:

**ESTABLISHED, FIN-WAIT-1, FIN-WAIT-2, TIME-WAIT, CLOSED**

And these from the receiving (passive) side:

**ESTABLISHED, CLOSE-WAIT, LAST-ACK, CLOSED**

Now here comes the question:
I have modprobed the nf_conntrack_ipv4 module to both sides to check the connection states in /proc/net/ip_conntrack.

To my surprise, when the connection is terminated, both the initiator (active) and the receiver (passive) goes to the TIME-WAIT state.

I would expect only the initiator to go through this state, and the receiver just close the connection.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

UPDATE: How do I perform this test

I have a virtual machine with IP 10.0.0.1 (Ubuntu 12.04) and I start two ssh connections to 10.0.0.2 (Debian 6) from it (10.0.0.2 is a VM as well). I check the ip_conntrack of both ends and this is what I get.

```
root@machine1:~# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | grep 10.0.0.1
tcp      6 431997 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53925 dport=22 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53925 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 431944 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53924 dport=22 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53924 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2

root@machine2:~# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | grep 10.0.0.1
tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53925 dport=22 packets=206 bytes=19191 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53925 packets=130 bytes=18177 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
tcp      6 431947 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53924 dport=22 packets=16 bytes=4031 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53924 packets=17 bytes=3741 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
```

So far everything looks fine. Now I disconnect one of the ssh connections from machine2 and this is what I get:

```
root@machine1:~# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | grep 10.0.0.1
tcp      6 431989 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53925 dport=22 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53925 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
tcp      6 117 TIME_WAIT src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53924 dport=22 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53924 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2

root@machine2:~# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | grep 10.0.0.1
tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53925 dport=22 packets=211 bytes=19547 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53925 packets=133 bytes=18925 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
tcp      6 115 TIME_WAIT src=10.0.0.1 dst=10.0.0.2 sport=53924 dport=22 packets=31 bytes=5147 src=10.0.0.2 dst=10.0.0.1 sport=22 dport=53924 packets=25 bytes=4589 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are seeing both the ends going into TIME_WAIT state ? Because I can see in my tests, that the end which first sends the FIN, only goes to TIME_WAIT state. Can you explain us how you are testing this thing ?

Comment: Just added an example of how do I perform the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux TCP stack and conntrack have two different visions of the TCP connection. What you're seeing in `/proc/net/ip_conntrack` is different from what the kernel sees. The kernel state is stored in `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/tcp6` and can be displayed with `netstat`.

As seen here: https://serverfault.com/questions/313061/netstat-and-ip-conntrack-connection-count-differ-by-order-of-magnitude-why both counts differ. I presume that if you look at `netstat`'s output you will only see one end in `TIME-WAIT`

Comment: I guess that's the right answer :)
Thank you! It works as expected if I check the states with "netstat -nat"

Answer (score 0):

This is to prevent a new connection getting stale segments still floating around in the 'net from the old connection messing it up.

Comment: I read this, but the question is about why I see the TIME-WAIT state to both ends. This state should only be there in the node initiated the connection termination and not the other one (according to what I read so far).

Comment: TCP connections have data flowing in both directions.

Comment: According to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:TCP_CLOSE.svg one end will initiate the termination (active end) of a connection and only this will go through the TIME-WAIT state. The passive end should just close it. The same is what I see in different books as well.
Do I miss something here?